# How to remove subviews from superviews and redraw on a click a button click?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How to remove subviews from superviews and redraw on a click a button click?

```
float padding = 5.0;
        float view_width = 95.0;
        float view_height = 120.0;
        int rows = 0.0f;
        int columns = 0.0f;



        UIView *myAddedView ;


        for (int i=0; i<[product.CorrentAnswer intValue]; i++) 
        {
            if(i%3 == 0 && i > 0)
            {
                columns = 0.0f;
                rows += view_height;
            }

            myAddedView =[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding+columns, rows, view_width, view_height)] autorelease];
            myAddedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


            CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake( 40, 100.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f);
            UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:myImageRect];

            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",product.imagename];
            [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
            [myAddedView addSubview:myImage]; 
            [viewarray addObject:myAddedView];

            [self.view addSubview:myAddedView];
            columns+= view_width;   
        }
```

i want to remove myAddedView from self.view?

hope to get answer very soon....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by assigning a tag to `myAddedView` ....

code change :

```
myAddedView =[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding+columns, rows, view_width, view_height)] autorelease];
            myAddedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//add this line
myAddedView.tag = 10;
```

and on the button click(when you want to remove the subview) write :

```
if([self.view viewWithTag:10]!=nil)
{
   [[self.view viewWithTag:10] removeFromSuperView];
}
```

thanks

Comment: well thanks for such a quick reply mate but i just did this with the help of following code  if (viewarray.count>0) {
   for (UIView *view in viewarray)
   {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
   } 
   
  }

Comment: I don't know why you are using this viewarray because system itself has provision for all views added on it..... so you just need to tag views with different values........ this will help you to save memory. thanks

Answer (score 0):

the answer from user698952 is okay, adding a tag is the way to go.

```
myAddedView.tag = 10;
```

If you have more than one view with the same tag you have to change the code for removal a little bit.

```
UIView *someView = nil;
while (someView = [self.view viewWithTag:10]) {
    [someView removeFromSuperview];
}
```